# Procedural generation algorithms in Ruby

Tags: ruby, procedural-generation

Greetings!

As part of Ruby learning, I am working on a project that involves procedural generation, namely terrain generation and such. It happens to be in Ruby, however after the long weeks of searching and experimenting I am turning to you lot with the question or, more accurately, a plea. This is a two-fold question.

- Are there any Ruby implementations of the procedural generation algorithms (focusing on world - terrain, rivers etc)?
- Are there any libraries akin to [libnoise](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net) that provide procedural generation functions?

I have looked into Rb++ wrapper for libnoise, however it fails to compile on my system (Windows machine), moreover it is quite daunting to a novice such as myself. I have been porting various C, C++ implementations to Ruby, however I would prefer a robust and fully functional solution, if there is any.

Thank you for your answers! Be gentle, this is my first use of the Stack Overflow.  <sub>*Mipey*</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at this: [Ruby Quiz 173](http://rubyquiz.strd6.com/quizzes/173).
Sounds like you're mostly breaking new ground, as far as Ruby, though.. Start a github repository, ask on ruby-talk who wants to help :)
Addition: [A stackoverflow question about procedural generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155069/how-does-one-get-started-with-procedural-generation).

Comment: Useful link, thanks for bringing it to my attention! As for breaking the ground, well, I'm still a beginner, but I'll consider sharing any noise modules I manage to come up with... should it come to that.